# Keep ratio of viewBox when window size changed

Tags: javascript, svg

I want keep the ratio when the browser window changed so the viewBox has allways the size of the screen, but it scales the viewBox down when I try the code below. Can someone help me further?

```
viewPort.setAttribute("width", screen.width);
viewPort.setAttribute("height", screen.height);
viewPort.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 "+(screen.width-(screen.width+window.innerWidth))+" "+(screen.height-(screen.height+window.innerHeight)));
```

Comment: It looks like you are setting the viewbox to be a negative size. That invalidates the viewbox.

Comment: OK, I try to use Math.abs but it does also scales the viewBox down.

Comment: If we call _screen.height_ **sh** and _window.innerHeight_ **wh**, then your equation is **sh-(sh+wh)** which equals **sh-sh-wh** which equals **-wh**. Taking the absolute value of that is the same as just using **wh**.

Comment: So what would be the correct way? :)

Comment: I put up an answer, because I can't embed code in a comment. Basically, just use the window dimensions for everything.

Comment: Surely you just want the viewBox to be constant?

Comment: Yes Robert. I want the viewBox constant (screen size).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I think we are all confused about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirements are not clear.  I think you may be confused about the terminology, and what the `viewBox` actually does.

- **Viewport** refers to the size of the `<svg>` element on the page.  Sometimes called the canvas.  Its size is set by the `width` and `height` attributes.
- **viewBox** describes the bounds of the *content* of the SVG.  Its purpose is to tell the renderer where all the content is.  The renderer uses these dimensions to work out how to scale the contents to fit the viewport.

Do you just want the SVG to be exactly the same size as the browser window?  If so, then all you need to do is:

```
viewPort.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
viewPort.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
```

You do not need a `viewBox` at all.  The SVG won't scale, but it will match the size of the browser window.

However if you do want your SVG to scale to fit the window, then you do need to have a `viewBox`. But the viewBox has to be set to the size of your SVG **contents**, not the SVG canvas/viewport.

Normally the `viewBox` will be *constant*. You do not change it when the browser resizes.

In the example below I have set the viewBox to match the position and size of the ellipse element.  I have added a purple rectangle to represent the actual viewBox dimensions.  Note that the viewBox area is scaled up or down as needed to fit the window (and viewport).  By default it is scaled to fit completely inside the viewport.  But you can change that behaviour with the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

```js
var viewPort = document.getElementById("mysvg");

function setViewportSize() {
  viewPort.setAttribute("width", window.innerWidth);
  viewPort.setAttribute("height", window.innerHeight);
}

// Update SVG size when browser is resized
window.addEventListener("resize", setViewportSize);

// Set initial SVG size
setViewportSize();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <rect width="100%" height="100" fill="rebeccapurple"/><!-- rect the same size as the viewBox -->
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50"/>
</svg>
```

In fact you don't need a resize listener at all.  You can do it with CSS only.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <rect width="100%" height="100" fill="rebeccapurple"/><!-- rect the same size as the viewBox -->
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Paul. I want set the viewPort and viewBox to the screen size so it will stay costante there. So when the Browser size is changed I don't want to scale the viewbox. I need the viewBox because I use a slider to scale the content.

Comment: For example my screen size is 1600x900. The viewPort and viewBox is set to this size. Now when I change the Browser size to the half for example, the viewBox is scaled down which I don't want. The viewBox should be scaled to 1600x900 for example.

Comment: Then you should probably just be setting the viewBox width and height to the same thing as the SVG width and height. A [mcve] would still be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you Paul. It worked correct (I use some other code which has affect the scaling).